# Loop through a table and encode a field with SHA256 base64 hash

Tags: sql-server, base64, sha256, database-cursor

I need to update a column that currently contains a plain text password with its own SHA256 base64 password. To do so I'm using a cursor to loop through each record and  encode the password, but after execution all records have the same encoded password.

```
DECLARE @hash AS VARBINARY(128); 
DECLARE @h64 AS VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @pass AS VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @id AS INTEGER;

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR 
    FOR SELECT [ID] FROM dbo.Table
OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN   
        SET @pass = (SELECT [Password] FROM dbo.Table WHERE ID = @id);
        SET @hash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @pass);
        SET @h64 = CAST(N'' AS xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@hash"))', 'varchar(128)');
        UPDATE dbo.Table SET [Password] = @h64;         
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @id;  
    END;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;
```

Comment: **Don't hash passwords without using a salt!**

Comment: `UPDATE @Table SET [Password] = @h64` should be `UPDATE @Table SET [Password] = @h64 where ID = @Id`

Comment: @Dai thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DaleK Oh god! i did't realized. Stupid me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [**Don't hash passwords without using a salt!**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

  - Ideally use a hash-function designed specifically for password hashing like bcrypt instead of the SHA family (as bcrypt has a configurable strength value and includes all parameters and fields in a single string value whereas hashing manually means needing to store the hash and salt separately).

    - However bcrypt is not natively supported by SQL Server.
    - Also avoid `PWDENCRYPT` as it's deprecated and doesn't let you specify the hashing algorithm used, use `HASHBYTES` instead.
  - You can still generate salts securely using `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` which is a cryptographically secure RNG (it uses values provided by the operating system which may be PRNG or hardware-based RNG).

    - Note that it is safe to use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` in an `UPDATE` statement without a `WHERE` clause because it will generate a new number for each row.
- You don't need a cursor - you can do this in a single `UPDATE` statement.

  - `UPDATE` statements behave the same whether they're used with a cursor or not - so if you want to update a single row then you must specify the `WHERE [primaryKey] = pkValue` clause.
- **Always avoid storing binary data as Base64-encoded strings** - store binary data as `binary(n)` or `varbinary(n)`.

  - This is because SQL uses case-insensitive collation by default but Base64 is case-sensitive (Base16 is case-insensitive), so doing a query on a Base64 column may return incorrect results.
  - Base64 values take 33% more space than `binary` values - and encoding/decoding makes each operation far more expensive.
  - Base64 values are not SARGable when used in a query already using `binary` values unless you Base64 encode all values - which is just silly.

Here is how I would do it (assuming I couldn't use bcrypt):

```
ALTER TABLE
    dbo.Table
ADD
    [Salt] binary(16) NULL;

GO -- `GO` is necessary when using ALTER TABLE statements in the same query-batch as UPDATE statements.

ALTER TABLE
    dbo.Table
ADD
    [PasswordHash] binary(32) NULL; -- store hashes as binary values, not strings. SHA-256 produces a 256-bit (32-byte) long hash, so use a fixed-length `binary(32)` column.

GO

-- The [Salt] and [PasswordHash] columns need to be set in separate `UPDATE` queries (or using a single `UPDATE FROM` query) because of how `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` works.

UPDATE
    dbo.Table
SET
    [Salt] = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM( 16 );

UPDATE
    dbo.Table
SET
    [PasswordHash] = HASHBYTES( 'SHA_256', [Password] + [Salt] );
    -- T-SQL uses `+` to concatenate binary values. Don't use `CONCAT` because it will return a `varchar` value with undefined conversion semantics from `binary` values.

GO

-- Finally, remove the old password information and make the new columns non-NULLable:

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table DROP COLUMN [Password];
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table ALTER COLUMN [Salt] binary(16) NOT NULL;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table ALTER COLUMN [PasswordHash] binary(32) NOT NULL;
GO
```

#### Notes on `RAND` vs `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`

As stated, `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` is a cryptographically secure RNG whereas `RAND` is not, so `RAND` must not be used for generating Cryptographic Salt values.

But I'd like to demonstrate another interesting difference: `RAND()` will return the same value for every row in a query whereas `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` always returns different values. See for yourself by running this query:

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (
    rowId int        NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    cgr   binary(16)     NULL,
    rng   binary(16)     NULL,
    rng2  binary(16)     NULL
);

INSERT INTO @foo ( cgr, rng, rng2 ) VALUES
    ( NULL, NULL, NULL ),
    ( NULL, NULL, NULL ),
    ( NULL, NULL, NULL ),
    ( NULL, NULL, NULL ),
    ( NULL, NULL, NULL );

SELECT * FROM @foo;

UPDATE
    @foo
SET
    cgr = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM( /*length:*/ 10 ),
    rng = RAND();

--

SELECT * FROM @foo;

--

DECLARE @i int = 1;
WHILE @i <= 5
BEGIN

    UPDATE
        @foo
    SET
        rng2 = RAND()
    WHERE
        rowId = @i;

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

SELECT * FROM @foo;
```

Gives me this final output:

```
id   cgr                                   rng                                   rng2
1    0x2DEB1D8A8DAB1F65373E000000000000    0x00000000000000003FC75AD042AE086F    0x00000000000000003FE2C5C607959DFF
2    0x4F7F050C335330AF43E6000000000000    0x00000000000000003FC75AD042AE086F    0x00000000000000003FEB46BAA0391C3E
3    0xB23F1C1C4C860A9652EE000000000000    0x00000000000000003FC75AD042AE086F    0x00000000000000003FDA62960990C897
4    0x44C604D79B0BB19167F9000000000000    0x00000000000000003FC75AD042AE086F    0x00000000000000003FC04FEA23759748
5    0xCF7F9A4FA4EDD605ECC2000000000000    0x00000000000000003FC75AD042AE086F    0x00000000000000003FE3A8FA18BD83A9
```

Notice how the `cgr` values are all unique while `rng` values are all the same - despite both columns being set in the same `UPDATE` statement. The `rng2` column has distinct values but only because each row was set individually inside a `WHILE` loop.

(The `rng` and `rng2` columns all start with `0x00...003F...` because `RAND()` returns a `float` (IEEE-754) value which has a defined binary representation).

Comment: Superb! Thanks a lot for your time and suggestions.